# breezejs: reject changes to specific property

Tags: javascript, breeze

Is it possible to reject the changes to a single property of a breeze object without rejecting ALL the changes to that object?

Say I have

```
// assume manager is an EntityManager containing a number of preexisting entities. 
var person = manager.createEntity("Person");
// assume Name and House are valid properties of a Person object
person.Name("Jon Snow");
person.House("Lannister");
```

But I **ONLY** want to discard the changes made to the objects `House` property.

Is this possible, if so, how would I go about doing it?

**Note**: I would rather not iterate of the `originalValues` property and just replace them like that. I guess, I'm looking for a more graceful solution like...

```
person.House.rejectChanges();
```

where `rejectChanges()` is called on the property itself or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the lack of a better solution I came up with the following code which seems to serve my purposes:

```js
function RevertChangesToProperty(entity, propertyName) {
  if (entity.entityAspect.originalValues.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
    var origValue = entity.entityAspect.originalValues[propertyName];

    entity.setProperty(propertyName, origValue);
    delete entity.entityAspect.originalValues[propertyName];

    if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(entity.entityAspect.originalValues).length === 0) {
      entity.entityAspect.setUnchanged();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `person.House` property has an **entityAspect**, you can call `rejectChanges()` on this property's entityAspect. Property has an entityAspect if it is an object, that has other properties. Simple type like string or Int does not have entityAspect, properties of simple type just belong to another object

```
person.House.entityAspect.rejectChanges()
```

Comment: I understand that, however, in this case `person.House` is a simple property, not a Navigation Property that has an `entityAspect`.

Comment: Than you can call `person.entityAspect.rejectChanges()`. **Or** if you really want to restore original value of property of simple type, look into person's `entityAspect.originalValues` map. If you changed person.House property, it's original value will appear on `person.entityAspect.originalValues` map. If you go this way of restoring propertie's values read this carefully about entityState http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/change-tracking

Comment: I understand how to `rejectChanges`. My question is along the lines of rejecting the changes to a specific property without using `originalValues` to accomplish that. I guess I was hoping for some magical, uber secret breeze properties that I haven't already read about. It sounds like the solution to my question will remain just that, magic. Thank you for your contribution.